# Generate DTOs with mapstruct in a maven modular projet

Tags: java, spring, maven, mapstruct

I have a java web application i'm using `Spring 4.3.12.RELEASE` and i want to integrate `mapstruct` to automatically generate `DTOs`.

To start, i created a new standalone project with some facke classes and it works fine so i can find my new generated classes *impl.java.

After that, i create a new maven module in my project with the same classes and the same pom file but i the plugin doesn't work and the impls wasn't generated!

This an example of what i have :

```
public class SimpleSource {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    //constructors and getters and setters
}
public class SimpleDestination {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    //constructors and getters and setters
}
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SimpleSourceDestinationMapper {

    SimpleDestination sourceToDestination(SimpleSource source);

    SimpleSource destinationToSource(SimpleDestination destination);

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${version.proj}</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-dtos</artifactId>
    <name>service-dto</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.pasteur</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>service-dto</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: This `<version>${version.proj}</version>` will not work...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thnx for your comment, I deleted all the occurences of ${version.proj} but  the generation mapstruct doesn't work

Comment: I'm using CDI and Spring in my current project, can i make any problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed this plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and added this in the maven-compiler-plugin plugin:

```
<!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
<path>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</path>
```

so my pom looks like :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ........

        </plugins>
```

It works fine and I hope that can help anyone else !

Comment: You had 2 plugins generating impl classes. Most probably there was some mixup with that. Great that you resolved it. Btw the `maven-processor-plugin` was missing in your question. It would have been spotted more easily if it was there